# Perl: foreach array of strings, split strings, set each string to a new array

Tags: perl

I've got a string input, lets say it's:

```
junk 0 0 :::1000
junk 0 0 :::1001
junk 0 0 :::1002
junk 0 0 :::1009
```

I want only the last digit of the `100X` number, and I want to place it in a string, and populate an array with these strings.

I have the following code

```
my @lines = split /^/, $input;

foreach my $line (@lines)
{
  my ($garb, $long_ports)  = (split /\s*:::\s*/, $line);

  my ($garb2, $ports) = (split /10/, $long_ports);

  if ($ports < 10)
  {
    my ($garb3, $ports2) = (split /0/, $ports);

    #Add 0 since 0 port is split to empty string
    if (length($ports2) == 0)
    {
      $ports2 = "0$ports2";
    }

    #Create file name format
    @locked_ports = ".X$ports2-lock";
  }
}
```

When I `print "@locked_ports"` I only get the value `.X9-lock`, when I want all 4.

How do I make it so `@locked_ports` contains all 4 of the strings?:

```
.X0-lock
.X1-lock
.X2-lock
.X9-lock
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it runs, when you modify your code as follows

```
my @lines = split /^/, $input;

foreach my $line (@lines)
{
 chomp($line);
 my ($garb, $long_ports)  = (split /\s*:::\s*/, $line);

 my ($garb2, $ports) = (split /10/, $long_ports);

 if ($ports < 10)
 {
   my ($garb3, $ports2) = (split /0/, $ports);
   #Add 0 since 0 port is split to empty string
   if (length($ports2) == 0)
   {
     $ports2 = "0$ports2";
   }

   #Create file name format
   push @locked_ports, ".X$ports2-lock";
  }
}
```

you have to `push` the locks at the end of `@locked_ports` and to `chomp` the $line to get rid of newlines

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to use `push` to add each desired result to the end of the array. Here's an example snippet:

```
foreach my $line (@lines) {
    chomp $line;
    if ($line =~ /(\d)$/) {
        push @ports, ".X$1-lock";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

one quick thing to try is change this:

```
 @locked_ports = ".X$ports2-lock";
```

to:

```
push @locked_ports,"X${ports2}-lock";
```

Also make sure you are using `use strict'` and `use warnings;` and post the snippet where you declare `@locked_ports` and print it.